# CursorLoader/adapter not displaying correct values

Tags: android, contacts, simplecursoradapter

I'm attempting to query Nickname and SIP Address from the contacts. The issue I'm running into is that both of them are stored in DATA1 column. So when I run a query, I only retrieve the Nicknames. What's a method of retrieving both of them and passing them into the `SimpleCursorAdapter` below?

```
CursorLoader c = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri, CONTACTS_NUMBER_PROJECTION2, Data.MIMETYPE+" ='" + Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE+"'", null, ORDER);

private static final String[] CONTACTS_NUMBER_PROJECTION2 = new String[] {
SipAddress.DISPLAY_NAME,
SipAddress.SIP_ADDRESS,
BaseColumns._ID};
```

Using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, both `Nickname.NAME` and `SipAddress.SIP_ADDRESS` are nicknames.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contact_list, null,  
                          new String[] {Nickname.NAME, SipAddress.SIP_ADDRESS},
                          new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2}, 0);
```

The screen shot looks like this. The smaller font should be the Sip Address.

If I change `Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` to `SipAddress.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` I get Sip Addresses instead of nicknames. I'm not sure how to get both to show up.

[image]

Update:

I changed Nickname.NAME and SipAddress.SIP_ADDRESS to Nickname.DATA7 and Nickname.DATA*, respectively. Added 'null' for my selectionArgs. I actually do get both the nickname and sip address to show up but not on the same row:

[image]

Update 2:

I stored the sip and nick name value under StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME and StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, then loaded them with the adapter. I change the selectionArgs to Data.MIMETYPE+" ='" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE+"'"

This was the result:
[image]

```
 if (key.equals("alias")) {
                            contacts.add(ContentProviderOperation
                                    .newInsert(
                                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                    .withValueBackReference(
                                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                                            0)
                                    .withValue(
                                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                    .withValue(
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                            userDict.get(key).toString())
                                    .build());
                        }
if (key.equals("sipExt")) {
                            contacts.add(ContentProviderOperation
                                    .newInsert(
                                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                    .withValueBackReference(
                                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                                            0)
                                    .withValue(
                                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                    .withValue(
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                                            userDict.get(key).toString())
                                    .build());
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) says, Contact details for different MIMETYPEs are stored in different records in one contacts Data table, and have one-to-one relation to contactId. Because of that it is practically impossible (I think) to get sip number and nickname in one cursor row.

Here is database scheme fragment [image: courtesy of BreatheInMyVoid / habrahabr.ru]

For inserting two StructuredName values you shoud use single insert:

```
    contacts.add(ContentProviderOperation
                                .newInsert(
                                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withValueBackReference(
                                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                                        0)
                                .withValue(
                                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                .withValue(
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                        currentNickName)
                                .withValue(
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                                        currentSipNo)
                                .build());
```

To show data from two different mimetypes in the form of a list, **two-column GridView** may be used, if correct ordering (first by contactId, then for mimetype) is set.

If **full** row customization is wanted, you can create ArrayList of simple objects containing sip-nick pair, fill it using data from two cusors (nick and sip) ordered by contactId and then use Array adapter to show them in listview.

Alternatively, you can load **two** cursors in a custom adapter: for nicknames and sipnumbers. Extend, for example, SimpleCursorAdapter, passing another cursor into its constructor along base cursor. Then in newView / bindView you can perform a lookup in the additional cursor and get corresponding data.

Comment: So get rid of the Data.MIMETYPE? By unknown column types you mean Nickname.DATA5, Nickname.DATA6, etc.?

Comment: Yes. The behavior of contacts provider is not specified in this case, but we can hope it to be sane. A small experiment

Comment: I changed Nickname.NAME and SipAddress.SIP_ADDRESS to Nickname.DATA7 and Nickname.DATA*, respectively. Added 'null' for my selectionArgs. I actually do get both the nickname and sip address to show up but not on the same row. Check the updated question, I added a screenshot.

Comment: Well this means that the data for the differenet mime types is indeed is stored in a single Data table in different records, distinguished by mimetype key. Then the only way to mix sip number and nickname in a single list view row is custom adapter. I will edit the answer

Comment: by the way, what are you going to do if several sip nos (or rarely) nicknames is connected to a single contact id?

Comment: Each contact will have only one sip and nickname. This custom adapter is a bit over my head. Can you give me a bit more guidance or links that describe what to do? Thanks.

Comment: look for custom contacts adapter here: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters

Comment: added array adapter solution

Comment: I should've mentioned this earlier but the field location of my data is irrelevant. The data could be in StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME and StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME rather than nickname and sip address. I'm having a hard time just loading any two fields to show up correctly.

Comment: this would be easy because given name and display name belong to one data table row but different fields. your original approach should work in that case

Comment: It's creating two rows now. Check my edited question with the new screenshot.

Comment: sounds strange... have you changed PPROJECTION_2 array accordingly?

Comment: Yes its StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME BaseColumns._ID. I still need the BaseColumns._ID otherwise I get an error.

Comment: I just added where the value are being inserted at the end of the question

Comment: AHA! So you ARE adding two records for one user! Insert both values in a single insert operation.

Comment: I thought you originally meant two or more nicknames for each contact. So what am I doing wrong? I have to do the .withValue(
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, userDict.get(key).toString()).build()); only once for each contact?

Comment: included fragment for inserting values into the answer

Comment: Got it. And I thought my adapter was goofing up. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: added previously overlooked GridView usage option to display data from different contact mimetypes in a single row.